# Sequentially select parts of a string similar to ngram

Tags: python, string

Here is the problem I am trying to solve.

For example there is this string

```
my_string = 'jan feb mar'
```

And I want to have sequentially generated items like this in a list. 
It is always true that the words in a string are splittable with `' '`.

```
my_function(my_string)
output = ['jan', 'jan feb', 'jan mar', 'jan feb mar', 'feb','feb mar','mar']
```

What I tried is below and it is not what I want.

```
my_string = "jan feb mar"
words_list = my_string.split(' ')
words = [' '.join(words_list[i:i+n]) for i in range(len(words_list) - n+1)]
words.extend(input_list)
```

Please help me out here. Thanks.

Comment: does the order matters in output

Comment: `itertools.combinations` does [something similar with a different order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list). Do you need to return a generator or is a list acceptable?

Comment: @komatiraju 
Yes, the order matters when making the strings. for example 'jan' cannot be after 'feb' or 'mar' and 'feb' cannot be after 'mar' 
so, 'feb mar jan' is not valid in the output list.

Comment: @ggorlen
returning a list is preferable.

Comment: Just for info, as you asked me in the other post, I've add an answer, In fact this a classic "All combinations of all length" so I've add it down there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?  Just create a lookup for sorting

```
import itertools 

def my_function(my_string):
    def subsets(s): 
      output = []
      for i in range(1,len(s)+1):
        output +=  list(itertools.combinations(s, i))
      return output



    my_list = my_string.split()
    my_order = {val:ind for ind,val in enumerate(my_list)}
    print(my_order)
    output =  subsets(my_list)
    output = [' '.join(sorted(list(i), key=my_order.get)) for i in output]
    return output
my_string = 'jan feb mar' 
output = my_function(my_string)

print(output)
```

Comment: This works well for my purpose. Thanks a lot!
Although when I pass 'jan' only it gave me an empty list while what I need is ['jan']

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to think about these combinations is a counting in binary. Given a list like `['jan', 'feb', 'mar']` you can think of each of your selections as being masked by a binary number. For example `110` would correspond to `jan feb`. Since you are looking for all the combinations you can simply count from 1 to the number of combinations and use the binary number to mask the selection. This makes for a very succinct solution:

```
words  = 'jan feb mar'.split()

def all_sets(words):
    l = len(words)
    for n in range(1, 2**l):
        binstring = format(n, f'0{l}b')[::-1]
        yield " ".join([word for flag, word in zip(binstring, words) if int(flag)])

list(all_sets(words))
# ['jan', 'feb', 'jan feb', 'mar', 'jan mar', 'feb mar', 'jan feb mar']
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is all `combinations` of all size (1, 2 and 3), combinations keeps order (permutations does the combination in every order)

```
from itertools import combinations
print(list(combinations(my_string.split(' '), r=1))) # [('jan',), ('feb',), ('mar',)]
print(list(combinations(my_string.split(' '), r=2))) # [('jan', 'feb'), ('jan', 'mar'), ('feb', 'mar')]
print(list(combinations(my_string.split(' '), r=3))) # [('jan', 'feb', 'mar')]
```

---

Now you need to do them automatically, so loop on the number of items in the input, and join each word

```
from itertools import combinations, chain

# pythonic way
def my_function(values):
    items = my_string.split(" ")
    return list(chain([' '.join(c) for i in range(1,1+len(items)) for c in combinations(items, r=i)]))

# loop way
def my_function(values):
    items = my_string.split(" ")
    result = []
    for i in range(1,1+len(items)):
      comb = combinations(items, r=i)
      result.extend(' '.join(c) for c in comb)
    return result
```

- `chain` is flatten the list of list in one list

## [`CODE DEMO`](https://repl.it/repls/UrbanVictoriousPhysics)

Answer (score 0):

using `permutations`

```
from itertools import permutations as per
res = []
my_string = 'jan feb mar'
l = my_string.split()
for i in range(len(l)):
    res.extend(list(per(l, i+1)))

res = [' '.join(i) for i in res]
print(res)
```

output

```
['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'jan feb', 'jan mar', 'feb jan', 'feb mar', 'mar jan', 'mar feb', 'jan feb mar', 'jan mar feb', 'feb jan mar', 'feb mar jan', 'mar jan feb', 'mar feb jan']
```

Answer (score 0):

[Mark's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62097977/6243352) is best in my opinion, but here's another take on it for good measure. This works with the [normal combinations of any length algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371887/making-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list) with a nested loop on the results to reorganize the output according to OP's spec. I'm returning a generator but most of the work is unfortunately up front.

I also moved the string manipulation to the caller. I don't see any reason to return anything but tuples which is a more flexible format than strings for this use case. The caller can always join the tuples as shown below (or do other useful things that serialization might prevent).

```
import itertools

def all_combs(L):
    combinations = [list(itertools.combinations(L, i + 1)) for i in range(len(L))]

    for i in range(len(L)):
        for j in range(len(combinations) - i):
            for comb in combinations[j][i+i*j:i+j+1]:
                yield comb

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(map(" ".join, all_combs("jan feb mar".split()))))
```

Output:

```
['jan', 'jan feb', 'jan mar', 'jan feb mar', 'feb', 'feb mar', 'mar']
```